# I cant access the req.user from passport outside of my routes folder. MERN stack redux node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, passport.js

I am trying to access the req.user that passport creates when doing a google o auth strategy. I can access the req.user in the routes file below, but when I try to access it in my userController file it is showing up as undefined.

Why is user accessible in routes file but not userController?

googleAuthRoutes.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin')
const cors = require('cors');
const axios = require('axios');
const Template = require('../models/Template');
const corsOptions ={
    origin: true, 
    credentials:true,            //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}

module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/auth/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['profile', 'email']
    }));

    app.get(
        '/auth/google/callback',
       passport.authenticate('google'),
       (req, res) => {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    );

    app.post('/templates/create', async (req, res) => {
        const { template, body } = req.body
        console.log(req.user)
        const newTemplate = new Template({
            template: template,
            body: body,
            _user: req.user.id  
        })
        try {
            await newTemplate.save()
                return res.status(200).json({
                    message: "Successfully saved template"
                })
        } catch (err) {
            return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    
    


    app.get('/api/logout', cors(), (req, res) => {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('http://localhost:3000');
    });
    app.get('/api/current_user', (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
    })
}
```

when I call the res.send(req.user) here above it sends the user no problem

But it is `undefined` with the `/templates/create` route middleware.

the console.log(req.user) is coming back as undefined??

index.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const keys = require('./config/keys');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
require("dotenv").config();
require('./models/GoogleUserModel'); // the user model must be placed before this services passport// this must be ran after requiring model bcuz this needs the model. ORDER
require('./models/UserModel');  
require('./services/passport');

const corsOptions ={
    origin:'http://localhost:3000', 
   credentials: true,      //access-control-allow-credentials:true
    optionSuccessStatus:200
}
const app = express();
app.use(cors(corsOptions))


mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
})
mongoose.connection.on('error', () => {
    throw new Error (`unable to connect to database: ${keys.mongoURI}`)
});


app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded( { extended: true }))
app.use(
    cookieSession({
        maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        keys: [keys.cookieKey]
    })
)
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./routes/userRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/googleAuthRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/messageRoutes')(app);


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).json({"error" : err.name + ": " + err.message})
    } else if (err) {
        res.status(400).json({"error" : err.name + ": " + err.message})
        console.log(err)
    }
})
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT);
```

Again, Why is the req.user available in the app.get to /api/current_user but available in a post request to /templates/create?

Im trying to add the user.id to the schema when it saves so i can retrieve each template by the user.id and not show everyone everybody elses templates lol

Comment: Where are you using the template middleware? Can you show the route its connected to?

Comment: HI Jason thanks for the reply, Im still racking my brain and cannot figure this out....j

Comment: Here is my userRoutes.js file